# Can we hide a certain user in WP?

Tags: plugins, customization, wp-admin, users, admin-ui

Is it possible to hide a user in Users panel of WordPress without using any plugin. I had achieve this using plugins but I want to do it the old fashion way if its possible, like write a code in functions.php or something like that?

Comment: Technically everything is possible... ...but to properly answer this so that you're provided with an answer you can 'accept' as being correct, you have to start the process and if you get stuck, update this question with the code you got stuck on.  When your question is open ended like this, you risk getting multiple answers, all of which work and then how do users determine which one is correct?

Comment: Re: "without plugins" -- The file `functions.php` is essentially a plugin that only runs in the context of its theme. Unless there's a theme-specific reason to hide this user, I'd recommend doing this in a plugin, as then the functionality will persist even if you change themes.